# Java Webservices and SOAP - Changing an element name

Tags: java, web-services, soap, element

I'm writing a java web service that returns a custom type. Everything works fine except when I look at the SOAP response it doesn't use the name "myType" - it uses "return"

This is my SOAP response - basically where it says "return",  I want it to say  "mytype"

```
S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:MethodResponse xmlns:ns2="http://myWebservice/">
         <return>
            <field1>sdf</field1>
            <field2>sdf</field2>
       </return>
      </ns2:MethodResponse >
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Class
package myWebserivce

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;


@WebService(serviceName = "myWebserivce")
public class myWebserivce{

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Method")
    public MyType Method(@WebParam(name = "string1") String string1, @WebParam(name = "string2") String string2) {

        MyType mt = new MyType();
        mt.setField1(string1);
        mt.setfield2(string2);

        return mt;
    }
}
```

MyType class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name="MyType") 
public class MyType {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }


}
```

SOLUTION

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;


@WebService(serviceName = "myWebserivce")
public class myWebserivce{

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Method")
    @WebResult(name="MyType")
    public MyType Method(@WebParam(name = "string1") String string1, @WebParam(name = "string2") String string2) {

        MyType mt = new MyType();
        mt.setField1(string1);
        mt.setfield2(string2);

        return mt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your web service class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to make sure `myType` is annotated with `@XmlRootElement(name="myType")`.  (You might need to annotate the method with `@WebResult(name="myType")` too.

(In Java, class names start with an uppercase letter so it should really be `MyType`)

Comment: Ok - I've added they MyType class above - I ran it like that and it still shows "return" in the SOAP. Have I added @XmlRootElement in the correct place?

Comment: @user1737391 Try `@WebResult`